# Using java dynamic proxies from native code via JNI causes crash

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am using java dynamic proxies (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/reflection/proxy.html) to create proxy interfaces for my objects. Everything works well when I try to invoke methods on these objects from java code to java code. 
 However, for some reason, when I try to invoke a method on this proxy from native code via JNI, I get an exception:

```
F art : art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: the return type of CallObjectMethodV does not match java.lang.String[] android.content.pm.IPackageManager.getPackagesForUid(int)

: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] in call to CallObjectMethodV
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] from long com.test.app()
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] "pool-11-thread-1" prio=5 tid=38 Runnable
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x12e36940 self=0x93a5dd00
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] | sysTid=22863 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x8edeb920
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=4 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] | stack=0x8ece9000-0x8eceb000 stackSize=1038KB
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470] | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #00 pc 0056d8de  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+238)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #01 pc 00539f6e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread9DumpStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+526)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #02 pc 00536f6b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZNK3art6Thread4DumpERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEEEEbP12BacktraceMap+75)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #03 pc 0038e868  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt8JniAbortEPKcS2_+1560)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #04 pc 0038f168  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9JavaVMExt9JniAbortVEPKcS2_Pc+120)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #05 pc 0013d112  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck6AbortFEPKcz+82)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #06 pc 00140c22  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck17CheckMethodAndSigERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+450)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #07 pc 0013faff  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPcNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+1295)
: art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:470]   native: #08 pc 0012e1fc  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI17CallObjectMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDPc+108)
```

I am guessing this is because the proxy interface has a generic return type (Object?) whereas the JNI code checks for the actual type (in this case String[]?).  Note that if I remove the proxy interface and invoke the object regularly (not through the proxy inteface), it works fine as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is a useful question, but to make it good, please include a [mcve] as well as the entire error message (that you get from the example).

Comment: Thanks Jorn.  I updated the question with the full stack.  As for the example, there is nothing really special there.  It's just using the default Proxy builder class from Java and then passing the object now to JNI and invoking it.  When it gets invoked is where I get that error message :(

Comment: No, you should include a runnable example. You want to be absolutely sure that you're talking about the same scenario. Sure people could come up with their own examples, but that's also extra work, that might even be wasted when the actual scenario is different or the problem was actually caused by something else. That's why it's important to create an MCVE.

Comment: I'd love to know about wether you fixed this issue? Or what happen. I come across the same problem at certain android devices

Comment: I also would really appreciate example code to show how you even got this far!  I am working on a similar issue.